# A thread for updating a RichTextBox.Text twice a second is not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, textbox

First of all - I'm very low skilled programmer. I am building the foundation of a simple music app for my bachelor degree project. My question is regarding a internal clock method that is meant to increase an int value by 1  *BPM* times a minute.

I've created an internalClock class:

```
public class internalClock
{

    // THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED WHEN THE THREAD IS STARTED
    public static void clockMethod()
    {
        int BPM = 135;
        int clockTick = 1;
        Form1 clockForm = new Form1();
        // infinite loop
        while (true) 
        {
            if (clockTick == 8)
            {
                clockTick = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                clockTick++;

            }

            clockForm.metrobox.Text = clockTick.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000 / BPM);
        }


    }
}
```

This is how I managed to get an access to the RichTextBox itself:

```
public RichTextBox metrobox
    {

        get { return metroBox; }
        set { metroBox = value; }

    }
```

In the main 'Program.cs' I've written what's meant to start a separate thread to run the clockMethod until the program is closed:

```
// THREADING
        // Create a thread
        internalClock oClock = new internalClock();
        Thread oClockThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(internalClock.clockMethod));
        // Start the internalClock thread
        oClockThread.Start();
```

It's not updating the text in the RichTextBox. Also, if I call the clockMethod() without creating a separate thread for it - the application freezes. Sorry for my amateur question, I'm just getting started with C# (yeah.. my uni is useless). What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Don't use threads/infinite loops, there is special class for you. [**Timer**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/C-Sharp-timer/)

Comment: But will it be able to work simultaneously with other methods and etc.?

Comment: Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) to see basic usage of the Timer class including how to use Timer.Elapsed (which is what you want). Edit: The previous link provided by Eser has essentially the same information.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I'm getting my hands on it :)

Answer (score 0):

So the above code has several problems, however I would encourage you to check out the Timer control that you can add to the form you want to do processing at a certain interval or in certain "ticks". [MSDN Form Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

With the timer you can remove that class you have and invoking a new thread, etc etc. I would read up on the Timer class in the given link and think about how you can re-work your application structure to fit that. The concepts for why that thread isn't working, etc, is frankly not that important for where you're at. I think you just need to focus for now on a tool that already does what you want it to do, which I believe is the Timer.

As a general note, you usually don't need to create a raw thread in .NET. As of .NET 4.0 you can access types called Tasks to perform multi-threaded logic and processing. If you find the need to do that later on, check that out. [Task Type MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Comment: @Yurieff No problem. If this answer is a sufficient solution don't forget to accept! Thanks.

Comment: The benefit of Timer is that you can set the interval to 60 * 1000 / BPM, and the Tick event will fire every 60 * 1000 / BPM ms. Using the Thread.Sleep in the original code doesn't take into account the execution time of the rest of the code so the update interval would be slower than the desired BPM. If the code in the Tick event takes longer than the interval it will hold up the next event though so there would be limit to how fast it could run depending on the code inside the event.